# PLS between error and negative loglikelihood in classification models?

Tags: classification, references, terminology, partial-least-squares

Consider a large but finite output space $\mathcal{Y}$.
Let $\Delta$ denote a loss function between $y^*$ and $\hat{y}$, i.e. $\Delta : \mathcal{Y} \times \mathcal{Y} \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{+}}$. One **heuristic** is to tune the parameters of a log linear model (or even nonlinear models)  to find parameters $\theta$ that maximize the covariance between the errors $\Delta(y_i, \hat{y}_i)$ and the negative log likelihood $l_{\theta}(\hat{y}_i)$. This is reasonable since we are tuning the parameters so that the probability assigned to the hypothesis varies according to its error and high error would imply low probability (roughly).

This **heuristic** seems like an obvious enough thing to do. Someone must have done it. Who did it? What's this technique called? Searching on google for PLS brings up many techniques but none of them seems to use my terminology.